# Excel date based Conditional Format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, conditional-formatting

I have got a license check tracker with dates entered when a check is done in column (E) and a date populates in the cell next to it in column (F) that is 90 days later for when the check must be done by next.

What I am looking for is to make the cells in column (F) with the dates the next license checks must be done, to automatically turn bright red if the date in the cell is within two week of the date you are viewing the sheet.

| E | F |
| --- | --- |
| Licence Check DATE | License Check Expire |
| 03/11/2021 | 01/02/2022 |
| 04/11/2001 | 02/02/2002 |
|  | 30/03/1900 |
| 03/11/2021 | 01/02/2022 |
|  | 30/03/1900 |

Comment: Thanks for the edit Scott

Comment: Use conditional formatting with the formula: `=F2<=NOW()+14`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply conditional formatting to the column with dates you want to format, then choose the `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` option and use the following formula:

`=AND(F2>(TODAY()-14),F2<(TODAY()+14))`

This will highlight all dates which are in range between the day which fell 14 days before and the day falling 14 days after `TODAY()` (assuming today is the day you're viewing the worksheet on).

Comment: That's great, thank you for your help

Comment: Glad I could help! Since it seems you're new on SO, please don't forget to accept the answer that helped you solve the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Hi, sorry for the very late reply. Yes I am new to SO, thank you for your help, support and advise. I really appreciate it !

Comment: No worries, happy to help!